# postgresql sequence related issue "id is getting repeated"?

Tags: java, node.js, postgresql, playframework

I have a table named `document` and its sequence `document_seq`.
I am using multiple stacks (node and play framework and database as Postgres) in my project. Let's say my last id of document table is 119, then I try inserting a row from node then it becomes 120 (document_id) then I try to enter to document table through play framework then it should generate 121, but instead of this, it is inserting 120 as id of column in document, so the document table generate duplication of id error. When I checked that with sequence after inserting data it is increasing +20 or more time from the last value.

For this issue

1. i have tried resetting the sequence_id by creating triggers, where it will reset sequence with the last document_id.
2. Also tried to delete document_seq and make document_id serial, but getting sequence error.

Comment: There might be caching involved with the play framework, i.e. instead of getting every sequence from the database, it gets a "chunk" of let's say 50 ids, and keeps them in memory to use until the next chunk is required. Since node doesn't know about this caching, it uses "reserved" ids and you get errors from the Play side when it uses cached ids.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a trigger. In PostgreSQL you can use the special data type `serial`, as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

If you create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE document (
    id SERIAL,
    text title
);
```

You can very easy insert data like this:

```
insert into documents (title) values('text');
```

and the sequence work correctly. `serial` is a shortcut or a macro and is translated to:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE document_id_seq AS integer;
CREATE TABLE document (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('document_id_seq'),
    text title
);
ALTER SEQUENCE document_id_seq OWNED BY document.id;
```

You can also use the above commands. It is important that you use `nextval` in the default part of the column definition. The secquence function `nextval` read and increase the sequence in one step.

Comment: thank u for the answer, but in play framework we have tight coupling with sequence, so if make id as serial it will give sequence related error.